# Unable to File Upload via sendkeys in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

I am unable to upload the file using sendkeys in selenium . Even I tried to upload file on different website . Even I change the browser . Earlier I was using Chrome now I tried on Mozilla also . I am getting an exception . Let me share the script below

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FileUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","c:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        driver.get("https://html.com/input-type-file/");
        
    
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("E:\\1.My Task\\My Task123");

    }

}


Error ----------------------

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : E:\1.My Task\My Task123
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-D3V0TN3J', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 92.0.4515.131, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 92.0.4515.43 (8c61b7e2989f2..., userDataDir: C:\Users\gunve\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54243}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: fe1a2bfd380827509bef42daa3cee01e
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
    at JavaNewLessons.FileUpload.main(FileUpload.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wepage contains any `input` tag with attribute `type` and value is file, you can directly do `send_keys`

So, You should replace

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("E:\\1.My Task\\My Task123");
```

with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("E:\\1.My Task\\My Task123");
```

Also I would suggest to have Explicit wait before you perform this operation.

**Update 1 :**

> Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative,
> procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution,
> or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The
> condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the
> wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns
> a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.
>
> ```
> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they make a good fit for synchronising the state between the browser
> ```
>
> and its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

**Code :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))).sendKeys("E:\\1.My Task\\My Task123");
```

You can refer here, and see what official says [click here](http://E:%5C%5C1.My%20Task%5C%5CMy%20Task123)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance ... As I m new ... So I watched video on explicit wait & tried to resolve the error .. But still failed ... I think I have to learn how about explicit wait properly ... Also if you got time please guide me with explicit wait for this code ... Thank you in advance ...

Comment: Sure, You can refer here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait, as well I have updated the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The error says clearly, that you are using a wrong path to the file to be uploaded.
`E:\\1.My Task\\My Task123` is not a valid path to file.
Also, this path have to include the file itself.
It can not just be a path to the folder.
It should be something like:

```
'C:\Users\yourName\picture.png'
```

Also the element to send the file to can be normally located by

```
//input[@type='file']
```

XPath, so your command should be something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\Users\yourName\picture.png");
```